# Confusion with dereference operator

Tags: c++

Just to be clear of the facts, I wanted ask

```
int i = 1;
int *p = &i;
i = *p;
```

What do you call the operator * on p? is called the dereference operator same as in line 3?

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I prefer the `int* p` syntax instead of `int *p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int i = 1;
int *p = &i;
```

The `*` is part of the syntax of a declaration.  `int *p` says that `p` is of type `int*`.

```
i = *p;
```

That `*` is a dereference operator.

But the fact that both use the same syntax is not a coincidence.  C's (seemingly bizarre) declaration syntax is largely based on the principle that "declaration follows usage".

One way to read the declaration

```
int *p;
```

is that it declares that `*p` is of type `int`.  It follows from that that `p` is of type `int*`.  Similarly:

```
int *a, b, c[20];
```

says that `*a`, `b`, and `c[blah]` are all of type int, so `a` is of type `int*`, `b` is of type `int`, and `c` is of type `int[20]`.  (Note that the correspondence between declaration and usage isn't perfect; `c[20]` is just past the end of the array, and doesn't actually exist.)

This is why (at least in one school of thought) the `*` in a pointer declaration goes next to the identifier, not the type.

Answer (score 6):

This is an example of a pointer declaration:

```
int *p = &i;
```

This is an example of a dereference operator:

```
i = *p;
```

Operators apply only to variables, not types, they are not the same thing.

Comment: That is not only *pointer declaration*; it is more. It is *pointer definition and initialization*.

Answer (score 4):

`*` in this case is not an operator, it's a declarator. When applied to a type it turns it into a pointer to that type.

You can think of `int*` as a type.

Writing it this way makes it more clear:

```
int i = 1;
int* p = &i;
i = *p;
```

Comment: But that introduces the danger of thinking that `int* a, b;` makes `a` and `b` both pointers.  Spacing it as `int *p` actually follows the language syntax more closely.

Comment: @KeithThompson I've edited it a bit. Hopefully I got the wording correct.

Comment: Actually, it's called declarator operator. when it used as prefix for a type it declares a pointer to a type.

Comment: @cpx Do you mean dereference operator? There's no such thing as a declarator operator.

Answer (score 1):

That's a pointer declaration, not a dereference operator.

From the [cplusplus.com tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/):

> I want to emphasize that the asterisk sign (*) that we use when
>   declaring a pointer only means that it is a pointer (it is part of its
>   type compound specifier), and should not be confused with the
>   dereference operator that we have seen a bit earlier, but which is
>   also written with an asterisk (*). They are simply two different
>   things represented with the same sign.

Answer (score 0):

To define pointer in this way

```
int *p = &i;
```

is somehow confusing. I suggest you use this (note the space)

```
int* p = &i;
```

But there will be a problem when defining more than one pointers in such way:

```
int* p = &i, * q = NULL;
```

So more clearly, define the pointer type first, and use that type to define variables:

```
typedef int* int_ptr;
int_ptr p = &i, q = NULL;
```